# Trigger.io active tab for tabbar

Tags: tabs, trigger.io

I have a tabbar in my trigger.io app and currently have the setactive parameter set on the function element for each tab, so when selecting a tab it highlights the tab. While this works as expected I noticed if I go back using the back button on android or a built in soft button in app

( history.back() )

The highlight is lost. Now I understand why it would get lost as its only explicitly told to highlight when tapped but I was wondering if there is a way to programmatically trigger the highlight or active state so when I navigate between tabs and use the back button it will keep the highlighted state properly for each tab section?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would probably to add an event listener to update the button state with:

```
forge.event.backPressed.addListener(callback, error)
```

Also see: https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/core/event.html

Comment: Antonie,  I think you may have mis understood my questions.  Im not looking to fire an event when the android back button is pressed. I have a tabbar at the bottom of my app. Each tab opens up a section in my app but if I click the back button and the previous page was a tab it goes back to that page but the tab is not highlighted. I guess the question is, are tabs accessible outside the tab scope, meaning can I access the tab information with some type of index and trigger it to attach the highlighted state?